# how stable is indigo?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

our team is currently using hydro, with most of our code in python 2.7 and some c++.

we're considering upgrading to indigo.

how is everone's experience with indigo so far?  is it stable?

we were just concerned that the upgrade will cause us any issues (i.e. compatible, stable, etc) that may delay our development.

would love to hear everyone's thought.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188072/how-stable-is-indigo?/) by [d](https://answers.ros.org/users/19443/d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used Indigo on a robot yet. The migration guide documents most of the breaking changes between Hydro and Indigo: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration . There aren't very many of them, and they're mostly just removing features that were deprecated in Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0